# Jquery countdown quarter of an hour

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I'm using [jquery Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) for a project. I want to show how much time people have to order something and recieve it next day.

Whatever I try I can only get this to work with full hours. So let's say I have an end moment time 16.00 then the countdown works. When I use 15.48 then the script doesn't work and shows a wrong time.

So the idea of my script is to show the timer on days that are in my array. 
Then I want to show the timer only between `orderstart` and `orderexpiry` time.

I just can't see what I'm doing wrong (perhaps I'm looking too long to it). Any help greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="order-countdown" data-orderstart="09.22" data-orderexpiry="17.15">
  <div class="countdown hidden"><span class="time">00:00:00</span></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
  initCutoffTimer(["1","2","3","4","5"]) //array with days to show timer
});

function initCutoffTimer(showDays){ 
 var dt = new Date(),
  time = dt.getHours(),
  year = dt.getFullYear(),
  month = dt.getMonth()+1,
  day = dt.getDate(),
  dayNr = dt.getDay(),
  currentDate = dt.getFullYear() + '/' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day,
 $.each(showDays, function(index, showDay){
    showDay = showDay.trim();
    showDay = parseInt(showDay);
    var showCountdownTill = parseInt($('#order-countdown').data('orderexpiry'));
    var showCountdownFrom = parseInt($('#order-countdown').data('orderstart'));
    if(dayNr == showDay && time >= showCountdownFrom) {
      $('#order-countdown .countdown .time').countdown(currentDate +' '+showCountdownTill+':00')
        .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
          var format = '%-H:%M:%S';
          $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
            $('#order-countdown .countdown').removeClass('hidden');
      }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $('#order-countdown .countdown').addClass('hidden');
      });
    }
  });

}
```